# Renting and driving in UK with Left Hand driving licence

Tags: driving-license

I hold a LHD driving licence living outside UK; can i rent and drive in UK with Left Hand driving licence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drivers' licenses from countries where drivers sit on the left side of the vehicle are accepted for car rentals in the UK. I have a license from a left hand drive country, and have regularly rented cars in the UK driven there on holiday for decades.

Two notes, however, might be useful:

First, licenses commonly are silent as to side of the road. If your license says "LHD only," or something like that, it's possible that a rental agency wouldn't accept it...and it also possible that if you were stopped by a police officer, the officer wouldn't accept it as valid either.

Second, all bets are off if the license is not printed in English, that is, using Latin characters. If not in English, you should obtain and carry with you an International Drivers Permit from your home country, a multi-lingual translation of your license. It's still possible that a rental agency wouldn't accept your license, but your chances of success would be higher.

Comment: Thanks David; very much appreciated